# Sanitize stream from stdin using node.js

Tags: node.js, regex, sanitization

I have this script:

```
let stdin = '';

process.stdin
  .setEncoding('utf8')
  .resume()
  .on('data', d => {

   stdin+= d;
});


const regexs = [
  [/(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{7,300}/g, function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {
    return match.slice(0,2) + 'xxxxx' + match.slice(6);
  }]
];


process.stdin.once('end', end => {

  for(let r of regexs){
    stdin = stdin.replace(r[0], r[1]);
  }
  console.log(stdin);
});
```

and I am using it like so:

```
 echo "ageoageag ageagoie ag77eage" | node sanitize-stdin.js
```

and I get this:

```
agxxxxxeag agxxxxxie agxxxxxge
```

but I really am only looking to replace a string of length 6-300 if it has numbers in it. So the output I am looking for is:

```
ageoageag ageagoie agxxxxxge
```

anyone know how to replace the string only if it has at least one number in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is modified, how about this modification?

In your script, `match` in the function of `replacer()` is the splitted string. When `"ageoageag ageagoie ag77eage"` is inputted, each value of `ageoageag`, `ageagoie` and `ag77eage` is given as `match`. `replacer()` returns all cased of `match` as `match.slice(0,2) + 'xxxxx' + match.slice(6)`. By this, `agxxxxxeag agxxxxxie agxxxxxge` is returned.

In order to process only `match` including the number, how about this modification? Please modify the function of `replacer()` as follows.

#### From:

```
return match.slice(0,2) + 'xxxxx' + match.slice(6);
```

#### To:

```
return /[0-9]/.test(match) ? match.slice(0,2) + 'xxxxx' + match.slice(6) : match;
```

#### Result:

```
ageoageag ageagoie agxxxxxge
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

If the values inputted are separated by a space like `ageoageag ageagoie ag77eage`, how about this modification? In this modification, `const regexs` is not used.

#### From:

```
for(let r of regexs){
  stdin = stdin.replace(r[0], r[1]);
}
```

#### To:

```
stdin = stdin.split(" ").map(function(e) {
  return e.length > 6 && e.length <= 300 && /[0-9]/.test(e) ? e.slice(0,2) + 'xxxxx' + e.slice(6) : e;
}).join(" ");
```

Comment: that would work I think, two step regexes are often times way simpler than one fancy regex

Comment: @Alexander Mills Thank you for replying. I apologize that my proposal was not useful for your situation. So I proposed one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? Also if this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.